# How do I switch back to ruby 1.8.7 from ruby 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have following ruby versions (I'm on linux (Ubuntu))

```
rvm list

   ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p378 [ i386 ]
=> ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
```

When I do:

```
sudo rvm --default use 1.8.7
```

My RVM Ruby version changed to:

```
=> ruby-1.8.7-p302 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.1-p378 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.2-p0 [ i386 ]
```

But it doesnt change my system gem version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux]
```

How to change my system ruby version to 1.8.7?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using:

```
sudo rvm --default use 1.8.7
```

changes it for root, not for you. Remember, RVM is primarily for creating a sandbox for you as a user, not for the system or another user. Since you've been using `sudo`, which is a bad thing, you probably have things that are now owned by root, not you, which will cause your Ruby system to behave like it's psycho. Use `chown` to switch the ownership of all files in `~/.rvm` back to you.

Use:

```
rvm system
```

to switch back to the default Ruby in `/usr`, `/usr/local` or `/opt`. Which one is called at that point will be determined by your PATH settings.

To switch between versions in your account that display when you do `rvm list`, use:

```
rvm use 1.8.7
```

or simply

```
rvm 1.8.7
```

If you want to make that the default version that is sticky, add on `--default` to the end of the command.

Answer (score 2):

```
 rvm use 1.8.7 # WITHOUT SUDO
```

And don't use sudo with RVM. RVM is a thing to avoid sudo.

Comment: Hi fl00r, thanks for the reply used rvm use 1.8.7 and got Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p302
but when i do ruby -v still getting ruby 1.9.2p0 (2010-08-18 revision 29036) [i686-linux], any idea.. thanks again

Comment: Yes. Your PATH for system Ruby is above of the PATH to rvm, so it uses system ruby at first. You can do: 1. remove system ruby, 2. or change your PATH variable.